# How to run testng appium-java maven project build in Intellij idea from command line?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, command-line, testng, appium

I have a maven project (appium/java) which is written in Intellij idea. To run the test i have to run the testng.xml file. 
I want to run my test script from command line. How can i do that? I have found various link to run testng.xml from command line but none of the solutions works for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your's is a maven project, you can use the option **mvn clean test** from command line after navigating to your project path. This will run the tests in the testng.xml file

In case if you have multiple test xml files you can use [Surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/). To your pom.xml you need to add something like :

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFiles}</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Add as many suiteXmlFile tags required & it should point to the location of your test1.xml, test2.xml etc.,
Then in command line use the command

```
mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile.suiteXmlFiles=path/to/test1.xml
```

In case if you want to run multiple test xml files you can use the command

```
mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile.suiteXmlFiles=path/to/test1.xml,path/to/test2.xml
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I didn't get your answer. can you please elaborate it?

Comment: I mean you can use maven commands to achieve this. First in command line navigate to your project, then run the command "mvn clean test". This will run the tests in the testng.xml file

Comment: I have multiple xml file, such as test1.xml, test2.xml etc how can i run that? If i want to ren test1.xml file only, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your appium cases using testng.xml file then you can use surefire plugin of maven to run your testng file using maven. And maven you can use command line to run.

So basically you can run maven command which will internally run your tesng.xml file using surefire plugin. Add the surefire plugin in your pom file in build section as below. And then run  mvn test command it will work.

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>Give your testng.xml file   path</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```